# How can I use a Grid inside a Block Grid Column in Foundation 6?

Tags: html, css, gridview, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I would like to have a responsive list of items, dynamically fetched from the server (so the number of items is unknown).
According to Foundation 6, the block grid is the way to go. I have used the block grid successfully to show images, but when I try to create a grid inside a block grid column, it doesn't look too good.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="foods row small-up-1 medium-up-3 large-up-4">
    <div class="food column">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 medium-4 large-3 columns picture ar-wrapper ar-4-3">
                <div class="ar-container">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 medium-8 large-9 columns data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns title">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns description">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns restaurant-name">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

None of the additional classes interfere with the width of change any float settings.
The result looks like this:
[image: Block grid column from the example above]

The tall block on the left is the "large-3 columns" element and the selected (blue-ish) element is the "large-9 columns" large div (it's made on a large screen). So by the looks of it, the block grid column has more than 12 simple grid columns.

I appreciate any help or alternative solutions on how to solve this.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what comprises your responsive list of items ? Right now I'm assuming you would want the title, description and restaurant name in that. If that is right, then don't mention separate rows, have one row and inside that you can have three divisions with appropriate classes and contents. It will be more clear if you can put an image of what you are expecting.

Comment: That is exactly what I expect to see, but I solved the issue by just having one row and entering a large number of <div class="small-12 medium-6"></div> elements, which contain the restaurants. It seems to render fine, so that I have a row with 20 "medium-6" columns. This seems like a hack and would have loved to use the block grid instead, which seems to have this exact purpose, but this solved my issue.